# How do I insert a div into another div with plain Javascript(no JQuery or other library)?

Tags: javascript, html, insert

How do I insert an HTML div into another div using plain JavaScript? I have found examples of how to do this with jQuery, but I have not found out how to do it with plain JavaScript. The platform I am developing for is limited to plain JavaScript.

I would like to create a grid that has a column and row count that depends on an XML file. I wanted to create a div for each category, and for each piece of content in that category I wanted to add a div. I have been able to create a single div using the following:

```
document.createElement("img");
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `document.getElementById("whatever-id-of-the-div").appendChild(document.createElement("img"));`

Comment: That is not a div, that's an img tag....are you sure you want a div in a div or an img in a div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be added at the bottom of an existing element, you want to use `appendChild()`.

Start by setting the new element to a temporary variable:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
```

Then make any updates to the new element (e.g., add a class, set the `id` attribute, etc.) and append it to your target element:

```
document.getElementById.("TARGET_ID").appendChild(newDiv);
```

If there is other content in the target div already, and you want to place the new element in a specific location **other than** the end, you can identify the appropriate child element of the target div and use `insertBefore()` instead.

Lots of information on this can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild